# How to remove duplicate records when I treat record (A,B) the same as (B,A)

Tags: postgresql

I have table with columns `col1`, `col2` (and some other).

```
col1, col2
1, 2
2, 1
2, 2
```

In my case records 1,2 and 2,1 are the same, how can I deduplicate this table using this definition of duplication?

Comment: Do you want to physically delete those rows, or just a SELECT statement? If you want to `DELETE` them: do you have a unique column in that table?

Comment: Just SELECT statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To just select those rows, use:

```
select distinct 
         least(col1,col2) as col1, 
         greatest(col1,col2) as col2
from the_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. This can also be expanded for more than two columns. Just add the columns in concat and use split_part to add more columns

```
select split_part(split_k,',',1) as col1 ,split_part(split_k,',',2) as col2 from
  (
    select distinct string_agg(split,',' order by split) as split_k from 
      (
      select row_number() over () as row_num,unnest(string_to_array(concat(col1,',',col2),',')) as split from new
      )t 
    group by row_num
  )k
```

A fiddle for this:https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rNZN3nuQnc6Dm64JwNtSX3/0